# nonstandard check of nodes in tree

Tags: javascript, treeview

I need some suggestions how could I implement a function to check the next to last node which is a last child on this level too with its children when I click parent node. To be more specific, I will try explain it better on simple example. When we have a tree like this:

```
Node1
Node9
Node11
Node15, Node14
(Node4, Node5 - Node15's children), (Node2, Node3 - Node14's children)
```

When I click e.g. Node9, with it should be checked Node1, Node15, Node4 and Node5 elements as well.

I have a function to check every children nodes for given parent and I wanted to use it but I found some difficulties to recognize the next to last node. Is any easy method to check if a node is the next to last for given path?

So far I have something like that:

```
function checkNonstandard(click, check) {

if(click.siblings().length>0) {
    click.siblings().each(function() {
        if($(this).is('ul') || $(this).is("li")) {
               // if($(this).children().is(":last-child")){
              // if($(this).children().length == 0){
                     //   $(this).removeAttr('checked');
//here I wanted with no luck to put a condition to check only the next to last node with children
                }
                else{
                     checkStandard($(this).children(), check);

//this is a function to check every node for given parent and its ancestors
                }
        } else if($(this).is("input")) {
            if(check==true) {
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thx in advance for any suggestions how to handle it.

Comment: something like $(this).parent().find(">*")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dandavis for reply, but I could not find it usefull after all. I tried few tests and almost got it. I changed code to:

```
if(click.siblings().length>0) {
    click.siblings().each(function() {
        if($(this).is('ul') || $(this).is("li")) {
        if(($(this).children().children().children().length < 1) && !($(this).parent().is(":last-child"))){
                    $(this).children().removeAttr('checked');
                   // $(this).parent().not(":last-child").removeAttr('checked');
                  //  $(this).parent().removeAttr('checked');
                 }
                else{
                     checkNonstandard($(this).children(), check);
                }
        } else if($(this).is("input")) {
            if(check==true) {
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            }
        }
    });
```

}

It works almost ok, because checks only lowest level leafs which are children of the next to last node (n-1) last child , but leaves checked also rest of (n-1) nodes. So far I do not know why any of two commented by me conditions does not work.